# PHP echo text if variable is blank

Tags: php, variables, echo

I am trying to echo €00.00 if my variable $amount equals zero

I have done something wrong can you help??

Code

```
while ($row9 = mysql_fetch_array($result9))
{
$amount = $row9['amount'];
}
//$amount = $amount / 60;
//$amount = round($amount, 2);
if $amount == 0 echo "<b>Balance: &#8364;00.00</b>";
else
echo "<b>Balance: $$amount</b>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the if/else in the loop, and you have some invalid syntax (missing parens and double $).  So:

```
while ($row9 = mysql_fetch_array($result9))
{
  $amount = $row9['amount'];
  if ($amount == 0)
  { 
    echo "<b>Balance: &#8364;00.00</b>";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "<b>Balance: $amount</b>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding extra `$` to the `$amount`, try this:

```
if ($amount == 0) {
   echo "<b>Balance: &#8364;00.00</b>";
} else {
  echo "<b>Balance: $amount</b>";
}
```

In fact you can make your code a bit more readable/standard like this:

```
if ($amount == 0)
{
  echo "<b>Balance: &#8364;00.00</b>";
}
else
{
  echo "<b>Balance: $amount</b>";
}
```

Comment: The parentheses around the condition are required.  It's not a question of readability.

Comment: The parentheses are still missing the in the first code example.

Comment: @waiwai933: I had corrected an error in the OP's code, posted his code there and **that is the reason** later I suggested him a better coding style.

Comment: @Web No doubt. Nevertheless, you still were suggesting that he use the first example, which was the reason we were pointing that there were no parentheses.

Comment: In your last example, if the database returns `'0.00'` for `amount`, `if (!$amount)` will evaluate as `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I've moved the if statement inside the while loop, cleaned up the code and removed the extra $ sign that was on the last line.

```
while ($row9 = mysql_fetch_array($result9)) {
    if ($row9['amount']) == 0 {
        echo "<b>Balance: &#8364;00.00</b>";
    } else {
        echo "<b>Balance: $row9['amount']</b>";
    }    
}
```